# object provides an interface in UML

Tags: object, interface, modeling, uml

I have three object :`object1`,`objectA`,`objectB` .

and also have an **interface**

How can I model as the following:

an `object1` provides an **interface** from `objectA` to `objectB`

Comment: what do you mean "object1 provides interface from objectA to objectB"? Typically objects are instances of Classes; Classes provide and/or require Interfaces.  Perhaps `object1` is the interface?

Comment: thank you @sfinnie . i don't know how can i model this sentence?could you please clarify your estimation a bit ?

Comment: You can't model the sentence as it's written. Or rather, it's ambiguous. See @Eoin's answer for two possible interpretations.

Comment: I agree with @sfinnie maybe could rewrite your meaning ...
Do you want to model that your object1 use the interface of from objectA and provide it to objectB? objectA is a part of object1 or in other words does object1 wrap objectA?

Comment: Hi @sfinnie ,@Red Bread
i really don't have more information than this line of requirement,i try a lot to find solution.yes it is ambiguous for this reason i post a question.
you can post answer as you understand from this sentence

Comment: @user2019510 "yes it is ambiguous for this reason i post a question".  No, the point is: it _is_ ambiguous.  No one here can tell you what 'the answer' is.  There are several good options below that give possible interpretations.  You'll only find out which (if any) is right by gaining clarification from whomever stated the requirement. If this is homework/an assignment then you need to ask your tutor.  Tell him/her you're practising good engineering by clarifying requirements.

Comment: hi @sfinnie here is the clarification of requirement: object1 is the instance of class1 that provides an abstraction layer between objectA and objectB ?

Comment: hi @RedBeard could you please check the clarification?

Comment: @user2019510: in that case, have a look for the Adapter Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are two immediate interpretations of what you want.  Either you have an interface ("Interface1") that acts as a shared interface implemented by ClassA and ClassB OR you want the interface to be the way that ClassA and ClassB interact.  I'm not sure which you mean.

In any case, the first option, where the interface is implemented by both is modelled like this:
[image]

The second option, where the interface is used to allow interaction is modelled like this:
[image: Interface for interaction]

Comment: thank you @Eoin ,here is the clarification of requirement: object1 is the instance of class1 that provides an abstraction layer between objectA and objectB.i don't know which one of your interpretation conform to this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, that is you want to create an UML diagram in where one class implements interface (Producer) and another uses it (Consumer) then I would say you'd have few choices:

1) Denote inteface explicitely, and use realization relationship to indicate implementation of interface, and dependency relationship to indicate usage:

[image]

2) Use lollipop notation to denote exposed interface, and dependency to indicate usage.

[image]

3) Use ball and socket notation (UML 2.0)

[image]

Comment: thank you @Sebastian K ,here is the clarification of requirement: object1 is the instance of class1 that provides an abstraction layer between objectA and objectB.i don't know which one of your answer?